# Problem with data cast on the GPU in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Im trying to do an image classifier, but im having a problem with the data cast on the GPU.

```
def train(train_loader, net, epoch):

  # Training mode
  net.train()
  
  start = time.time()
  
  epoch_loss  = []
  pred_list, label_list = [], []

  for batch in train_loader:

    #Batch cast on the GPU
    input, label = batch
    input.to(args['device'])
    label.to(args['device'])
    
    #Forward
    ypred = net(input)
    loss = criterion(ypred, label)
    epoch_loss.append(loss.cpu().data)

    _, pred = torch.max(ypred, axis=1) 
    pred_list.append(pred.cpu().numpy())
    label_list.append(label.cpu().numpy())

    #Backward
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
  
  epoch_loss = np.asarray(epoch_loss)
  pred_list  = np.asarray(pred_list).ravel()
  label_list  = np.asarray(label_list).ravel()

  acc = accuracy_score(pred_list, label_list)
  
  end = time.time()
  print('#################### Train ####################')
  print('Epoch %d, Loss: %.4f +/- %.4f, Acc: %.2f, Time: %.2f' % (epoch, epoch_loss.mean(), 
  epoch_loss.std(), acc*100, end-start))
  
  return epoch_loss.mean()


for epoch in range(args['epoch_num']):
  train(train_loader, net, epoch)
  break #Testing
```

Model already is in cuda, but i get error that says

```
Input type is torch.FloatTensor and not torch.cuda.FloatTensor
```

Whats the problem with `input.to(args['device'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** According to the OP, an aditional `data.to(device)` before the train loop caused this issue.

> you are probably getting a string like `0` or `cuda` from
> args['device']; you should do this:
>
> ````
> 'cpu') #pass your args['device'] ``` so then use `device` to move the
> model to GPU:  ``` model.to(device) ```
>
> then call the model with:
>
> ``` for batch,(data,label) in enumerate(train_loader):
>
>     #Batch cast on the GPU
>     data.to(device =device)
>     label.to(device =device)
> ````

Comment: Hey, thank you for answer. I did what you said, including when i passed my model to cuda, it was the same way i did with data: net = net.to(args['device']), but with model its working...

Comment: Did it answer your question? If yes please mark as accepted, if not please let me know to provide another one.

Comment: No, what I meant is that I had already done what you said, I had also done this when I cast the model on the GPU, but I still have the problem when I try to cast the data. When i do data.to(device=device), where device='cuda', its still accusing that data.type() is a torch.FloatTensor

Comment: Oh man, now i see wheres the problem. I completely forgot that i had to do ´´data=data.to(device)´´ and not just ´´data.to(device)´´. Thanks, your answer helped somehow